# Toad Import - Change column value based on which excel worksheet the data came from

Tags: toad

I am trying to import to a table an excel file with 3 worksheets. For one of the columns I would like to vary the value populated based on which worksheet it came from. Is there a way to do this with Toad Import. The sheets look the same and have the same columns. But if it is sheet 1 I want a certain column to be be ABC, if sheet 2 XYZ, sheet 3 ETC. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I load Excel files frequently, but I didn't notice such an option. So I went to see the loader once again, step-by-step, checked carefully what it offers - nope, there's nothing like that.

A workaround, quite simple, is to edit the Excel file and create that column. Then

- enter ABC into the first cell of that column
- select the cell
- double click the bottom right corner
- it'll auto-populate all rows in that worksheet with ABC (in that column)
- do the same for other sheets

---

Another option is to set column's default value, e.g.

```
alter table test modify ident varchar2(3) default 'abc';
```

You'd have to do that for each sheet you load, modify 'abc' to 'def' etc.

---

Or, if you switch to SQL*Loader (there's that option in the same menu as "Import table data"), create a control file which utilizes the `CONSTANT` keyword, e.g.

```
load data
infile excel.csv
append
into table test
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
(name, 
 value, 
 ident constant "abc"
)
```

Just like in previous case, you'd have to modify the constant value before loading each worksheet's data.

Also, note that SQL*Loader can't load XLS file - you'd have to save each sheet into its own .csv file first.

---

Which option would I choose? Probably the first one; seems to be the simplest & the fastest.